# Cant Set Gap Between Footer ending and end of page

Tags: html, css, position

I want to set an element footer made up of several elements

the first element should have:

```
left: 944px;

top: 9749px;
```

the second element should have:

```
left: 715px;

top: 9819px;
```

the third element should have:

```
left: 718px;

top: 9852px;
```

fourth and final element should have:

```
left: 705px;

top: 9999px;
```

BUT I ALSO WANT MY FINAL ELEMENT TO HAVE:

```
bottom: 93px;
```

this doesn't occur and it's stuck to the bottom of the page as if i had given

bottom : 0px

Is this a problem with page height or something?

(P.S. I haven't constrained the height of the page/body in any way.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<footer>` tag and create a `<div>` tag in it with same name and style it.

```
.container-one {
  flex: 25%;
  display: flex;
}
```